# Python 3.7 code will not loop and returns a name error

Tags: nameerror

First of all I am very new to programming so bear with me.  I am having the following problems with my current code that I cannot figure out.  I cannot get the end to loop based on user inputs.  Now the code is returning a name error.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Thank you for your time.

```
def gcd(a,b):    

    start_over = "true" 
    while start_over == "true":



        while True:
            a = int(input("Enter your first positive whole number: "))
            if a < 1 :
                print(a ,"IS NOT A POSITIVE WHOLE NUMBER")
                print("")
                continue

            else:
                break
        while True:
            b = int(input("Enter your second positive whole number: "))
            if b < 1 :
                print(b ,"IS NOT A POSITIVE WHOLE NUMBER")
                print("")
                continue

            else:
                break

        if (b==0):
                return a
        else:
            return gcd(b,a % b)

        gcf = gcd(a,b)


        print("the GCD of", a,"and", b,"is: ", gcf)

        redo_program = input("To perform another computation type Y/Yes or to quit type N/No: ").lower()

        if redo_program == "y" or "yes":
            start_over = "true"


        else:
            start_over ="null"
            print("GOODBYE")



gcd(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code confuses and interweaves two parts. Presumably you want to

- Ask the user for two numbers
- Recursively evaluate the greatest common divisor of them

But the `gcd` function both expects two numbers as parameters, and also asks user to input the numbers (thereby ignoring the parameters), and also recursively calls itself.

The name error comes from the last line, `gcd(a, b)`, where you are trying to get the GCD of `a` and `b` - but `a` and `b` have not yet been input (since you only do it *inside* the function).

Even if that bit worked, your function would figure that in order to calculate GCD of two larger numbers, it would need to calculate the GCD of two smaller numbers beforehand. So far, so good - except that you never actually calculate the GCD of the smaller numbers, but instead ask user for new, unrelated pair of numbers to calculate GCD of, and forget about calculating the previous pair.

Also note that your `if b == 0` conditional has `return` in both branches, so no code below it in the `gcd` function will ever be reached.

So to do what you want, try to change your code to fit this pseudocode:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    calculate GCD without asking user anything

presume user wants to continue
loop while user wants to continue
    ask for two numbers
    calculate GCD
    print result
    ask the user if they want to continue
```

Also, you have some weird strings in there. It is not really an *error* unless I missed something to have the string `"true"` indicating a true value, or string `"null"` for a no value, but it is very, very bad form - there are special values `True` and `None` in Python for those roles (you even used `True` correctly in `while True`).